# Login Getting Error of code=422, message=Unprocessable

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit and Whenever i hitting the login button its goes in response.errorBody(). I just simply want to navigate through Retrofit. And In Logcat I am getting this Error.Can anyone help me out please. **Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=422, message=Unprocessable Entity, url=https://xxxxxxxxxx.com/api/signin}**.

**Login Activity**

```
   private void signIn(){
    String email = eName.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = ePassword.getText().toString().trim();


    if(email.isEmpty()){
        eName.setError("Email is required");
        eName.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()){
        eName.setError("Enter a Valid email");
        eName.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    if(password.isEmpty()){
        ePassword.setError("Password Required");
        ePassword.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    if(password.length()<8){
        ePassword.setError("Password should be atleast 8 character long");
        ePassword.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    RetroInterface retroInterface = RetroClient.getClient().create(RetroInterface.class);
    Call<LoginResponse> loginResponseCall =retroInterface.login(email,password);
    loginResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {

            Log.d("Login Response",response.toString());
             LoginResponse lResponse = response.body();
             if(response.isSuccessful()){



                 Log.d("token",lResponse.getToken());
                 Log.d("email",lResponse.getLoginrequest().email);
                 Log.d("password",lResponse.getLoginrequest().name);

                 Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Login Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();


             }
             else {
                 response.errorBody();
                 Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Response Error"+response.errorBody(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

             }

}

@Override
public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {
    Log.e("Error", t.getLocalizedMessage());

}
```

});
}

**API Interface**

```
 @POST("api/signin")
Call<LoginResponse> login(@Field("email") String email,
                           @Field("password") String password);
```

}

**Retrofit CLient**

```
public class RetroClient {

public static final String BASE_URL = "https://xxxxxxx.com/";
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
public static Retrofit getClient() {
    if (retrofit==null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

}

Comment: from where are you passing the base url?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add @FormUrlEncoded before @POST in API Interface as the request process may be of Url encoded. Moreover, make sure if you need to send the email and password as **Field** or something else.

Comment: Monim Kaiser-i added @FormUrlEncoded, but still getting same error. DO i need to pass Id also aur Token? Because of that its happening?

Comment: Try to test the api from Postman first. I think you will be able to find out then.

Comment: i did its working fine there. i will share the screenshot.